# How can I implement log4j2 (2.14.0) 'JSON Template Layout' in a mule application?

Tags: mule, log4j2, mulesoft

Log4j2 has implemented a 'JSON Template Layout'. I have been able to implemented this in a standard maven java application, however I am not able to implement it in a Mule 4.3 application. I have added the log4j2 (2.14.0) dependencies to my POM:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.14.0</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Log4j2 Appender Config

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <JsonTemplateLayout />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

And I see that they are loaded in the log, but I get an error:

> 2021-02-06 07:17:39,175 WrapperListener_start_runner DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout].
> 2021-02-06 07:17:39,179 WrapperListener_start_runner ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout for element JsonTemplateLayout: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'interface org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.util.RecyclerFactory' java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'interface org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.util.RecyclerFactory'
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverterRegistry.findCompatibleConverter(TypeConverterRegistry.java:103)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.convert.TypeConverters.convert(TypeConverters.java:412)
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.AbstractPluginVisitor.convert(AbstractPluginVisitor.java:151)

Is Mule somehow dynamically loading an older version of log4j2 that does not implement the 'JSON Template Layout'?

Answer (score 0):

Mule 4 provides log4j2 to applications. It is one of few libraries that actually may override application's libraries in Mule 4. You should use what is provided. Do not try to change any provided libraries with different versions, that is not supported.